# Series of numpy operations seem to depend on numpy arrays initialization

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm in the process of vectorizing a series of operations with numpy arrays. And in doing that, I'm getting different results in different executions of my code. I'm using `numpy.random.randn` to get numpy arrays of the shapes that I need and testing if my operations do what I want them to do. I sometimes get the desired results and sometimes I don't, even though it's the same series of operations.

In theory, the first row of `big_result` should be equal to `result_1`, while the second row equal to `result_2`. This happens sometimes. Other times the first row is correct, while the second one isn't. And other times, both are erroneus.

This is the code to reproduce the problem (I added some seeds I got by hand, in which the error happens and some where it doesn't):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2) # First row of big_result corresponds to result_1, the rest is wrong
np.random.seed(3) # First row of big_result corresponds to result_1, the rest is wrong
np.random.seed(4) # Both rows of big_result are ok

# My two vectors
a = np.random.randn(1000, 8)
b = np.random.randn(500, 8)

# Operation vector
c = np.random.randn(3, 6, 8)

# Matrix with both a, b
big_A = np.full((2, 1000, 8), np.nan)
big_A[0, :, :] = a
big_A[1, :500, :] = b

# Broadcasting used to enable the use of c with big_A
big_C = np.broadcast_to(c, (2, 3, 6, 8)).reshape((3, 6, 2, 8))

# First result (for a)
result_1 = np.linalg.norm(a[:, np.newaxis] - c[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=-1)
result_1 = np.min(result_1[np.newaxis], axis=(-1, 1)) # Shape: (1, 1000)

# Second result (for b)
result_2 = np.linalg.norm(b[:, np.newaxis] - c[:, np.newaxis, :], axis=-1)
result_2 = np.min(result_2[np.newaxis], axis=(-1, 1)) # Shape: (1, 500)

# I mask out this operation to avoid meddling of NaN values
arr_with_nan = big_A[np.newaxis] - big_C[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
arr_with_nan = np.ma.array(arr_with_nan, mask=np.isnan(arr_with_nan))

# Result for both a and b 
big_result = np.linalg.norm(arr_with_nan, axis=-1)
big_result = np.min(big_result[np.newaxis], axis=2)
big_result = np.min(big_result, axis=1)[0] # Shape: (2, 1000), where (1,) -> result_1; (2,) -> result_2
```

### Some remarks

`a` and `b` correspond to numpy arrays whose dimension in `axis=1` may vary. This is why I'm appending them in a big numpy matrix `big_A` with `np.nan` to fill up the values. Plus, my "operation vector", `c`, is being broadcasted to the shape `(2, 3, 6, 8)` so that it can be used for both `a` and `b` inside `big_A`. This broadcasting doesn't let me operate `big_C` and `big_A` immediately, so I had to reshape `big_C` to `(3, 6, 2, 8)`.

My guess is that I'm dealing with a rounding error. I've tried casting everything with `.astype(np.float32 or np.float64)` but it doesn't work. If I subsequently execute my code, it fails. How do I make sure my code works independently of initial values in `a` and `b`?

EDIT: I forgot to add my precise question.

Comment: When trying to get code like this work right, I prefer to use small defined arrays, e.g `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` rather than `random` ones much larger.  I can then display the whole array, and more easily check for errors.  Big arrays are nice for timing tests, and checking for memory errors; they aren't good for comparing methods that might have small floating point differences.

Comment: Don't `reshape` after `broadcast_to`.  Transpose if you must, or use `c[:,:,None,:]` to make a (3,6,1,8)

Comment: @hpaulj Following your suggestion, I removed `reshape` after `broadcast_to` and changed `big_C[:, :, :, np.newaxis]` to `big_C[:, :, np.newaxis, :]` which forced me to change `big_A[np.newaxis]` to `big_A[:, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]`. This fixes the problem. I made a for loop with a thousand iterations and they all tested `True` comparing `big_result` rows with `result_1` and `result_2`. Thank you. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reshape after `broadcast_to`. Transpose if you must, or use `big_C[:,:,None,:]` to make a (2,3,1,6,8)